# Cause of faulty EGR valve

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, leak, egr, range-rover

I recently had my diesel Range Rover sport serviced but the garage didn’t re-seat the fuel filter correctly causing a leak of fuel. At the same time, my engine light came on and it turned out to be clogged/faulty EGR valve. My question is, could the fact I drove several hundreds of miles with an unsecured, leaking fuel filter have caused the EGR failure?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not connected in any way.

The EGR deals with exhaust gasses. They can, over time, get plugged with soot or possibly have a mechanical failure (depending on design). The EGR only comes into play *after power generation*, and has no connection to the raw fuel or fuel delivery system. Unless the leak was directly spraying on the EGR, there's no way a leaking fuel filter could have caused this issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Could the loose fuel filter not have caused an imbalance in the fuel/air mixture therefore causing the issue with the EGR? Or could it have allowed any other impurities into the engine?

Comment: If it were running slightly lean it would potentially run hotter than normal which may not have helped the carbon levels in the EGR valve, but that a really outside possibility and it would likely have just accelerated failure, not caused it completely.

Comment: @Kieron - I really don't see how. It would have to be a HUGE leak ... one which dropped the fuel pressure enough to make it go lean ... the computer would have most like compensated for this. If the leak was large enough to truly make a difference, I doubt you would have been driving for a month as the smell would have been tremendous. Really, there should be no connection between what you describe and a faulty EGR.

Comment: @Kieron - I did miss one thing, you stated it is a diesel engine ... this would most definitely rule out a fuel/air mixture issue from low fuel pressure. The fuel filter is between the drop pump and the high pressure pump. As long as the high pressure pump is getting fuel, it will pressurize the injected fuel to the proper levels ... no imbalance. Also, a diesel EGR is very susceptible to carbon clogging just by the nature of things (ie: how a diesel engine runs). No surprise an EGR might go bad there.

Comment: Thanks for your replies - to clarify I was only driving about 3 days before the engine light came on and experienced loss of power from the EGR issue, but the leak was pretty huge and was pissing diesel by the time I got it to the garage. Was just trying to figure out if this negligence could have affected the car in any other way than my inconvenience before I play hell with them next week.

Comment: Consider how you play hell with them - they may, or may not, accept you as a customer next time... “sorry fully booked next week” etc etc

Comment: Oh I won’t be going back there as a customer, don’t you worry.

Comment: @Kieron - Something I didn't outright say: This is just pure coincidence between the EGR going bad and the fuel leak. Not good they left a leaking fuel line, for sure. Gas (octane) would have been far worse than diesel, but still not good.